# SHAREPOINT LIST - @@IDENTITY - VBA

Tags: sql, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve the ID of a newly inserted item in a SHAREPOINT list. ID is an autonumber field in the list.

Adding, updating, deleting records in the list is working.
However, the `@@IDENTITY query` always returns 0.

The `SELECT MAX(ID)` approach does not work, at it sometimes gets the previously added record's ID

I suspect that `@@IDENTITY` does not work with Sharepoint lists. Any suggestion is welcome

Thanks

```
Dim con as new ADODB.connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rec as New ADODB.recordset

con.ConnectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=" & MYDATABASE & ";LIST={" & MYLIST & "};"

con.open
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MYLIST (NAME) VALUES ('MYNAME')"
cmd.Execute

rec.Open "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NEWID FROM MYLIST", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

NewItemID=rec.fields("NEWID").value
'NewItemID is always 0
```

Comment: try getting the last record of rec.MovetoLast

Comment: rec.MoveLast seems to work if I use 'ORDER BY ID' in my selection query. Thanks